# How can i create server certificate for wcf service?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I created my first WCF service application that will run on IIS 7

The binding that i used is wshttpBinding.

Now, i wrote also client using Silverlight - and i can't create reference on the client that will be point on the WCF service because of the certificate issue.

How can i create server certificate for wcf service ?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the certificate (btw. default wsHttpBinding configuration don't need any certificate because it uses Windows authentication). The problem is in selected binding. [Silverlight does not support wsHttpBinding](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/256b3ac8-c28a-42ce-9853-a5c31409fc15) so you will not be able to call the service anyway. Use basicHttpBinding instead.

Comment: But in this way - how can i control on witch client will use the service ? i want to give the ability to use the service only client ( silverlight in this case ) that have the right user name + password -